# convert enum class too std::tuple

Tags: c++

I would like to be able to create a std::tuple based on the enum value passed as a template argument, if possible without using global variables.

```cpp
#include <tuple>

enum class Type
{
  eInt,
  eFloat,
  eDouble
};

template <Type... type>
class Test
{
public:

private:
  std::tuple < ? > m_data;
};

int main()
{
  Test<Type::eDouble, Type::eInt> t1;  // m_data = std::tuple<double, int>
  Test<Type::eInt, Type::eFloat> t2; // m_data = std::tuple<int, float>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step one, figure out how to convert *one* constant to a type:

```
template <Type> struct MakeType {};
template <> struct MakeType<Type::eInt> {using type = int;};
template <> struct MakeType<Type::eFloat> {using type = float;};
// ...
```

This lets you do e.g. `MakeType<Type::eInt>::type` to get an `int`.

Now you can do `std::tuple<typename MakeType<T>::type...>` (where `T` is the template parameter pack, renamed from `type` for clarity).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you

Comment: Could you explain why the compiler complains `error: template argument 1 is invalid
std::tuple<typename Maketype<T>::type...> m_data;` ?

Comment: There is my erroneous interpretation of your code
https://godbolt.org/z/ssY8P5z7E

Comment: Be careful, there is a type:insted of  `Maketype` should be `MakeType` with capital `T`!